# Does piling up downvotes help the site in any useful way?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, meta

I am new here, but I’ve noticed  that downvoting on this site tends to be quite virulent with respect to off-topic questions or questions which probably  are  poorly formulated.

Though I understand the therapeutic nature of up/downvoting in motivating users in doing better, I really wonder if an excessive use of this feature actually makes  it less effective in the end.

A few examples in the last couple of days:

1. [On which site is it easier to earn reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322281/on-which-site-is-it-easier-to-earn-reputation) ***-8***
2. [Prompt when I accept my answer within 2 days seems miswritten?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322278/prompt-when-i-accept-my-answer-within-2-days-seems-miswritten) ***-10***
3. [Is downvoting a well-written question by a beginner OK?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322271/is-downvoting-a-well-written-question-by-a-beginner-ok) ***-13***
4. [Should (and could) we require the tour badge (and/or rep) to give answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322249/should-and-could-we-require-the-tour-badge-and-or-rep-to-give-answers) ***-10***

Comment: Downvoting on Meta SE is different.

Comment: Different from what?

Comment: What I don’t understand is the aggressive attitude of this site...

Comment: Meta doesn't necessarily have to grow ...

Comment: No, the older answer doesn’t solve my problem. You didn’t explain why everybody is so aggressive here.

Comment: Why do you consider downvotes to be aggression anyway? We're not in a boxing ring; if I downvote a question it just means I disagree with the premise of the question most of the time.

Comment: @user070221 _"You didn’t explain why everybody is so aggressive here."_ Downvoting isn't equivalent to agressivity. That's just a misconception of yours.

Comment: @M.A.R.ಠ_ಠ - well, in no other SE site there are such virulent streams of downvoting like here...that must mean something.

Comment: Yes, of course. It means people find it easier to decide their stance on some site policy than to reasonably gauge the correctness of an answer. Check out other busy meta sites and you'd notice a similar pattern.

Comment: @M.A.R.ಠ_ಠ - I couldn’t find other SE sites with such an aggressive usage of downvotes like here, if you can suggest me any...

Comment: Sure - [Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com). You won't see as many on the homepage since most of the heavily downvoted questions end up getting deleted, but they easily have as many downvoted question there as here.

Comment: I have never connected my personal judgement that a post isn't useful ( == down vote) with an act of aggression, nor have I considered down votes on my own posts as an aggressive deed towards me. Can you elaborate where that misconception of the meaning of votes comes from? That insight might help in explaining for future visitors what to expect on the SE sites.

Comment: @gnat there might be dupes that apply but that specific one isn't it. That one is about off-topic posts (say the programming ones) and advocates to not down vote them not because they wouldn't deserve it but to make the closure and deletion of such post more effective. If anything, that seems to enforce the "aggressiveness" of MSE, not reduce it, or explain it, which is what the OP is asking about here.

Comment: @rene I fail to see your point sorry. My duplicate suggestion is based on what I read in this question, specifically this: "downvoting on this site tends to be quite virulent with respect to off-topic questions... I really wonder if an excessive use of this feature actually makes it less effective in the end"

Comment: @gnat well, you have a point but then it is unclear because none of the examples are off-topic on MSE, right?

Comment: None of the examples are off topic, and the meaning of voting on meta question doesn't really answer this question. Reopening.

Comment: I agree with @Catija, was about to reopen now. Also, I upvoted this very question since it's a valid discussion about voting culture here on MSE.

Comment: @rene - let’s put it this way. If you are to tell someone that you disagree with what they are saying, I think it is a good, respectful and civil practice to tell them once, probably twice, but insisting 10 or 20 times is definitely rude and in the end counterproductive. That’s my take.

Comment: @user070221 why rude? Can you try to explain how you consider downvotes to be "rude"? (Maybe better in chat if you got the time, to not clutter comments here)

Comment: @user070221 but it's not one person insisting 10 or 20 times, it's 10 or 20 different people. You're not suggesting they form a committee and agree which of them get to vote before actually voting are you? I think you misunderstand the purpose of voting, it's not there for the question asker or answerer it's main purpose is for everyone else who might read the question to tell them whether it is worth reading or not.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - there is nothing wrong with downvotes, but what’s the point of downvoting   10 or 20 times? I understand that they come from different users, but once a question has been  downvoted a few times, why insist? That’s extremely rude and unwelcoming!!! Can’t Meta users resist downvoting?

Comment: @user070221 I'm sorry you see it this way. Maybe think of that as a poll, asking people "What you think of [put something here]?". So suppose 100 people are asked and 95 people say "We don't like that thing". Is it rude? No, it's not. It's just stats, that later help to collect and analyze data. Suppose the poll is "What you think of Joe?", Joe might be upset that 95% of the people don't like him, but still, it's not really a reason to take it as being rude and unwelcoming. Is it? [cont..]

Comment: [cont.] And if people will lie or won't share their opinion just because other people said something else, it will totally ruin the whole purpose of the poll.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - if that’s the way this site works, I am sorry I misunderstood. I thought it was about questions and answers as other SE sites. Maybe this “statistical” aspect should be made clear as a welcoming banner to new users like myself.

Comment: @user070221 well, not exactly, it's more complicated than that, but yes, voting here is different in its very nature from voting on the "main" Q&A sites of Stack Exchange, and the votes are used as indicator to SE staff what is considered good by the community and isn't. Again, it's not accurate science, but that's the general idea, and downvotes do not mean "this post is bad".

Comment: I wrote my last comment in a bit more of a sarcastic manner than I had intended.  My point is that everyone complains about downvotes, and compares them to negative aspects that they were never meant to portray.  Doing so just highlights your misunderstanding of the purpose of voting, and makes it that much easier to dismiss your complaints regarding it.  If you want to discuss them constructively, you should probably be open to perhaps seeing how you might have it wrong.

Comment: @fbueckert - I’m active on other SE sites and I am quite aware of the positive function of the up/downvoting system. I am not complaining   about downvotes to my post here but as a more general aspect, apparently peculiar to this site. Sorry if it is not crystal clear to me how things work here.

Comment: @fbueckert: "*compares them to negative aspects that they were never meant to portray*" And yet they do portray them. Whether they were meant to do so is kind of irrelevant; what matters is whether they *do* so or not. Working against human nature is not an effective way to work with humans.

Answer (score 18):

> I am new here, but I’ve noticed that downvoting on this site tends to be quite virulent with respect to off-topic questions or questions which probably are poorly formulated.

Off-topic questions are downvoted to a.) decrease their visibility on the front page ([-8 is needed for that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117120/369802)), and b.) allow regular users to start voting to delete them. ([needs a score of -3 to avoid a 48 hour waiting period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/369802))

Questions tagged [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) get downvotes/upvotes depending on whether people agree or disagree with the proposed change. [Should (and could) we require the tour badge (and/or rep) to give answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322249/369802), for example, is such a feature-request.

This also happens sometimes on questions tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion). People that don't have the time to write an answer signal their agreement or disagreement with the premises in the question by using their up/downvotes.

There is something to say about not using your votes for (dis)agreement on questions tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), but to judge them by their merit: Is this a useful discussion to have? Have we had this discussion many times before, did the person putting this up for discussion do their research effort? Is the discussion clearly written, is it clear what we should discuss?

Looking at your examples, [On which site is it easier to earn reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322281/369802) and [Is downvoting a well-written question by a beginner OK?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322271/is-downvoting-a-well-written-question-by-a-beginner-ok) might well have gotten downvotes for being not a very useful discussion (easiest to get rep) or something that has been discussed over, and over, and over (downvotes).

Then there are questions tagged [support](/questions/tagged/support), they usually get downvotes for 'lacking research effort'. In other words, the downvotes usually mean 'you could've known this if you spent a few minutes trying to understand how the site works'. I guess those are the ones that I'd like to see a bit less downvoted: If there's no duplicate, or the info is not easily found... Having those downvoted a lot seems/feels unfair.

> What I don’t understand is the aggressive attitude of this site...

Downvotes may come across as mean or aggressive, but they aren't meant to be. They're meant to filter content and have good discussions rise to the top, and push the questions that are unclear, lack research effort, or aren't useful to the bottom/off the front page. Please don't ever take them personally.

Comment: I don’t understand if my question is still a duplicate.

Comment: Well, my overall impression of this site is a very negative one. Definitely not the place for me. Goodbye.

Comment: @user070221 at least part of your question seems born from not understanding the meaning of votes, so at least part of your question can be called a duplicate, I guess. I do think your question is asking for more than that though, that's why I chose to answer it instead of closing. I'm sorry you're getting such a negative impression you feel the need to go, but I can't keep you here against your will. Goodbye, and all the best!

Comment: @user070221 for a better or worse, [Do some Stack Exchange sites have nicer cultures than others? How does one develop a positive culture in beta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223684).

Comment: @andmyself - thanks, very pertinent and interesting post. Maybe Meta users could take a minutes or two from their  downvoting activity and read it.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell -I do appreciate your effort to try to be polite  with me, unluckily that’s not the culture of this site. Bye.

Answer (score 11):

I disagree with your assertion that downvoting is aggressive on this site.

I see people downvoting for reasons that I interpret are related to the suggestions for when to downvote on its tooltip.

Sometimes those downvotes on Meta sites merely indicate disagreement.

Of the four questions you linked to I agreed with one and upvoted it but the others I downvoted because I either disagreed with them, thought they lacked effort or were not useful for another reason.

Comment: I disagree with your view so I DV, hope you don’t mind.

Comment: Of course I don't mind, it's your vote.

Answer (score 10):

I think two key factors are at play here:

#### Downvotes may indicate disagreement rather than poor quality

The [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/meaning-of-downvotes-in-meta-vs-main-sites) linked by πάντα ῥεῖ, and the section "Voting is different on meta" in the Help Center article [What is "meta"? How does it work?](/help/whats-meta) explain that there are more reasons to downvote questions than just quality/usefulness: downvotes may indicate disagreement with the proposed solution or the way the question is framed. The Help Center says this is reserved for [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s, but in practice it often carries over to [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)s.

As a prime example, a discussion about the downvoting culture on this site might be very useful (even though similar discussion have happened in the past already). Yet, it's heavily downvoted. Let me explain why I *think* that happened (YMMV). Objectively speaking, this question is worded in a fairly neutral way (which is what we expect from all questions by all users on all sites in the network), except for the second word in [the original title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/322324/1). The word "aggressive" can be used in a neutral way, but it needs non-verbal support for that; when written down this way it sets the tone "you're doing it wrong" to the entire Meta community (even though that might not have been your intention). It *doesn't matter* that the rest of this post is well-written; it's the *first impression* that matters. The old Be Nice policy stated: **assume good intentions**. This is a responsibility of both the OP and the community. However, a poor choice of words can make users (both new ones and veterans) easily forget this.

#### Downvoted questions are visible for a longer period

On main sites, questions disappear from the homepage once they have a score of -4 or lower. On Meta, this is -8. Therefore, downvoted questions stay visible for a longer period and tend to accumulate more downvotes than on other sites.

### Does this help the site in any useful way?

Yes, it does. Suppose I have a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) topic in mind, and I search on the site before asking it (or I examine the 'Questions that may already have your answer' on the Ask Question page). If I see a similar question with a very low score, I might think twice before posting my similar-but-not-exactly-the-same question. And that's a Good Thing™.

Comment: You're omitting a very important part of the help center that many people forget. Downvoting for disagreement is really only supposed to be on FRs, not on discussions. I'm kinda tired of seeing honest attempts to understand and discuss the policy of the network receive tons of downvotes. These discussions are really important and helpful to others who want to understand.

Comment: The theory is indeed that it's *supposed to be* only on feature requests, but what I describe is the (hard to change) practice. Personally, I don't downvote questions like these, but I do understand why people do.

Comment: The practice might be changed if it were pointed out more often. Most of the time I see people talking about how voting is different on meta, we simply say "downvotes mean disagreement", so many people aren't aware that that only applies to FRs. I've done it myself. We've been teaching people wrong for years and now this is where we are. It definitely makes meta seem unwelcoming if you come here to ask why things are the way they are and get met with many downvotes just for asking.

Comment: The (only) problem I perceive with this post is already in the second word of the title. It *can* be used in a neutral way, but (for the lack of non-verbal communication) it sets the tone "you're doing it wrong" to the entire Meta community. It doesn't matter that the rest of this post is reasonably well-written; it's the first impresssion that matters. I bet that without that word it wouldn't be at -6 now.

Comment: It's the responsibility of both the OP and the community to *assume good intentions* (as the old Be Nice policy stated). However, a poor choice of words can make users (both new ones and veterans) easily forget this.

Comment: I think that's a fairer answer to this. It may be less rule-based but it's certainly more an honest representation of what happens here.

Comment: I've rewritten the answer now to reflect this. Still, IMHO the subsequent comments by the OP don't reflect a constructive attitude (though here undoubtedly some kind of reinforcement psychology is at work), so in that sense the users who downvoted this question certainly have some grounds to do so.

Comment: @Glorfindel: "*If I see a similar question with a very low score, I might think twice before posting my similar-but-not-exactly-the-same question.*" Sure. But will that be any different if you see it with a -4 vs. a -8 vs. a -20? I think by the time it gets to -4, everyone has gotten the point that people don't like it.

Comment: -8 won't be twice as effective as -4, no. I do think -8 is more effective than -4, if only slightly.

Comment: Do you realize that by linking to them, you're invoking the [Meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235225/295232), exposing them to more downvotes?

Comment: That would be a secondary effect, what impresses me is the DVs they have genuinely received so far.

Comment: There are also many, many duplicates which *didn't* receive downvotes even though they were poorly researched.