# What can we do with [culture]? It hasn't a tag wiki and most questions are old

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

The tag [culture](/questions/tagged/culture) doesn't have a tag wiki.

- Required tags: As of January 16th, 2024, there are 16 questions tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), three questions tagged [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), and one question tagged [support](/questions/tagged/support). One question is tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).
- 13 questions are 10 to 14 years old.
- There are seven questions created since 2015
- 2 questions were created in 2023; one of them was closed as a duplicate.
- Six questions have [culture](/questions/tagged/culture) and [etiquette](/questions/tagged/etiquette).
  The tag excerpt of the *etiquette* tag is

  > Etiquette is the norms and standards of accepted behavior and politeness in our community. The golden rule is "Think before you post."

---

Progress update:

- I submitted a tag wiki edit suggestion on January 15th, 2024.
- Related tags: [behavior](/questions/tagged/behavior), [community](/questions/tagged/community), [etiquette](/questions/tagged/etiquette), [policy](/questions/tagged/policy), [rules](/questions/tagged/rules).
- On January 16th, 2024 I found that [The Stack Exchange reputation system: What's working? What's not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387356/289691) has several answers using the word *culture*. As experienced users on tagging know, tags are added based on what is being asked, not on the answers' content, but also to draw the post to the attention of experts on the tag topic to get an answer from them concerning the tag topic.

### Resources

- Meta SE Help Article: [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Not sure what you ask here. If you want to burninate the tag I'm all for it, but please make it clear. (For examples just see the [tag:burninate-request] tag)

Comment: I'm not looking for [tag:culture] to be *burninated*. I searched and noticed that this tag exists, with no tag wiki. In the past, I was asked not to edit old questions, among other things, by mods and others, so I'm asking before doing any edits to questions having this tag and before adding the tag wiki.

Comment: OK, so I added my own opinion as answer.

Comment: An interesting recent finding related to *culture* not having a tag other than [tag:discussion]: [Do some Stack Exchange sites have nicer cultures than others? How does one develop a positive culture in beta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223684/289691)

Comment: I see, so you want to add the tag there. Well, not up for me to decide and I still think the tag is better be removed, but maybe better wait to see what others think.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda, I didn't mention wanting to add the "culture" tag to the "interesting finding" in my previous comment. I just shared a fact that looks interesting to me in this context. You are not doing very well as mind reader lately :P

Answer (score 6):

> What to do with [culture](/questions/tagged/culture)?

I think it should be burninated. It has no real usage, and the word "culture" is too vague to be used as a tag, in my opinion.

- When it's about culture in a sense how users should behave, the [etiquette](/questions/tagged/etiquette) tag appears to be fine, as you also quoted yourself in the question:

  > Etiquette is the norms and standards of accepted behavior and politeness in our community
- When it's about the culture of the company itself i.e. how things are operated, [policy](/questions/tagged/policy) can be used instead:

  > For questions related to the policies of Stack Exchange.

And otherwise, it can just be removed.

Comment: This answer is ten days old and has six upvotes and two downvotes. What do you think I should do next? Should this question be bumped, or is it fair to say there is a consensus about what to do with [tag:culture]?

Comment: @Rubén since you didn't ask to nuke the tag, and there are few who disagree with me here, I'd say just leave it as it is: no need to do anything. (Just my personal opinion, if you want to add tag wiki then go ahead, if you want to add the tag to more questions go ahead I won't roll it back, just don't flood.)

Comment: Thanks. I just submitted an edit suggestion for the [tag:culture]'s wiki.

Comment: Thanks @Rubén, the excerpt is approved, but not sure about the full wiki, sorry. I didn't reject but it feels too "noisy", probably better leave it for now, excerpt is enough, IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and for approving the excerpt. I might review again the tag wiki body later this or the next week.